# How does the performance of pure Nginx compare to cpNginx?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

There is now a Cpanel plugin to fairly easily setup Nginx as a reverse proxy on a Cpanel/Apache server. I've been simultaneously interested in setting up my first unmanaged VPS and my first Nginx server and as a masochist figured why not combine the two.

I'm wondering however if it's worth setting up a pure Nginx server vs trying out cpNginx on Apache?  My goal is solely to host WordPress sites and while what I've read raves about Nginx's is exceptional ability serving static at least as a reverse proxy, I am unclear if there is substantial benefit to running a pure nginx with eAccelorator over cpNginx on Apache for dynamic sites?  Regardless I'll be running W3TC on all sites to cache content, but am still interested if there are big CPU reductions running PHP scripts under pure Nginx over cpNginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cpNginx is a simple interface which doesn't make any difference in terms of performance. When proxying back requests to Apache from nginx, you will still be using Apache for all your PHP requests, while simply serving out images, css, js and other static files directly from nginx. This will offer better performance and lower resource usage as opposed to running only Apache.

Nginx + php-fpm ( without Apache ) is typically regarded as being faster and less resource-intensive when compared to a properly tuned Apache, but feel free to perform benchmarks to test it out.